# Protocol used for desktop application in load Runner 11

Tags: desktop-application, loadrunner

I have been using load runner for testing web based application.

Now i need to check desktop application using load runner.

Please guide me which **PROTOCOL** should be used to test desktop application ?

Answer (score 0):

choose any protocol and choose the application type as win 32 application on start recording window

Comment: This is a piece of advice that should be avoided as it lacks any basis in logic for which path to take.  IT is the architectural foundation of the application which guides your selection on communication protocols.  Otherwise just line all of the protocols up on a felt board, close your eyes and throw a dart at the board on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which protocol is used in your application.

There's a protocol advisor feature in LoadRunner which can probably help you detect the used protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Speak with the developers and architects

Read your installation manual

Examine your visio diagrams for the next upstream architectural component

Read the System design documentation

Look at a protocol analyser trace for the application layer protocol expressed

Examine the handshake and port assignment in a winsock recording for well known ports and any literals in the client to server negotiation

Then look at the output of the protocol analyzer in LoadRunner vugen and see if it matches your architectural hypothesis as to which item you should select.

OR, just pick your choice of Winsock, GUI, Citrix or RDP

Answer (score 0):

if its desktop based why do you need loadrunner , you have UFT and if you have network based connections to your desktop application , it is possible it is citrix protocol or any other by which application is connected to server . check for it and select protocol

Comment: Use of a functional test tool en masse to produce load is considered state of the art as of 1993.   Use the the transport level protocol for the production of server load is more efficient, allowing many more users per host with fewer resources per virtual user.  It also (mostly) results in a simplified communication stream to parameterize and time.

Comment: my friend you may be right to some extent, but the kind of question that was asked, gave an inside how much knowledge the person has on load testing. I believe you have a good experience on load testing then try simulating citrix protocol , behaves worse than using a functional tool. Thats why we have true client there in load runner

Comment: See last comment answer March 04, 2014